# Sapply list output with 2 columns, how to arrange in ascending order?

Tags: r

> trueFalseACT always have 4 colums, but can have 1 or 10 rows

```
      trueFalseACT <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), dim = c(4L, 
4L))



[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

>  str(trueFalseACT)
List of 28
     $ : logi [1:3, 1:4] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ : logi [1:4, 1:4] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ : logi [1:4, 1:4] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ : logi [1:5, 1:4] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...

> class(trueFalseACT)
[1] "list"
```

> list_sapply will always have 2 columns, row and col.
> dput to replicate:

```
 list_sapply <-  list(structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("row", "col"))), structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L), dim = 3:2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "col"))), structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), dim = 3:2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", 
    "col"))), structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), dim = 3:2, dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("row", "col"))), structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L), dim = c(4L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", 
    "col"))))



  list_sapply <- sapply(trueFalseACT,which,T)
list_sapply[2]
[[1]]
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   2
[3,]   2   3
```

I want that the rows in order 1,2,3 on list_sapply ...

Comment: I am running your code and it does not gives me that answer, are you sure it is ok?

Comment: there was a typo, its correct now

Comment: @FrakTool I updated my answer with your update of providing `list_sapply`. Is that what you are looking for? Your code for creating `list_sapply` (i.e., `sapply(trueFalseACT,which,T)`) does not return what you are providing from `dput` for me, as I mostly get `integer(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put each matrix in `list_apply` in order, you can use `lapply` and `order`:

```
lapply(list_sapply, \(x) x[order(x[, 1]), ])
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1

[[2]]
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   3
[3,]   3   2

[[3]]
     row col
[1,]   1   4
[2,]   2   1
[3,]   3   3

[[4]]
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   3
[3,]   3   2

[[5]]
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   4
[3,]   3   4
[4,]   4   1
```

To get the indices on `trueFalseACT` and put in order, you can use a combination of `which` and `order`:

```
out <- which(trueFalseACT, arr.ind = TRUE)
out[order(out[, 1]), ]
```

**Output**

```
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   3
[3,]   3   2
```

Comment: "\(x) x[order(x[, 1]), ]" does the trick, much simplier for me !
what means "\(x)" 
and which and order cant figure out how to use inside a for loop, 
the diference in lenght to convert to data frame its where I preferer your first anwser.

Answer (score 1):

This should work despite the number of rows and cols. However, I did not use `sapply` but a `for` loop.

```
row <- c()
col <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(trueFalseACT)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(trueFalseACT)){
    if(trueFalseACT[i, j] == TRUE){
      row <- c(row, i)
      col <- c(col, j)
    }
  }
}
cbind(row, col)
```

Since the iteration is first on the rows, it will always return the rows ordered

```
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   3
[3,]   3   2
```

Comment: if(trueFalseACT[[i]][x, y] seems that will work